# Deployed Wildfly Spring Boot JMS application not receiving Amazon SQS Messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I've been created a Spring Boot JMS application to receive message from a specific amazon sqs queue. Running as Java Application it **receive messages without troubles.** 
But when I deploy on a wildfly v10.0.0 server it not works.

So, here is my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class QueueListenerFadeApplication {

private SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory; 
@Value("${aws.access.key}")
private String accessKey;
@Value("${aws.secret.key}")
private String secretKey;
private static final Logger logger = 
Logger.getLogger(QueueListenerFadeApplication.class.getName());

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory() {
    final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new 
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}

 private SQSConnectionFactory createSQSConnectionFactory() {
     BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new 
BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
     final AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClient.builder()
             .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
             .withCredentials(new 
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
             .build();
     return new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(), sqs);
 }

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
     this.connectionFactory = createSQSConnectionFactory();
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Starting Queue Listener...");
    SpringApplication.run(QueueListenerFadeApplication.class, args);        
}
```

}

Here is my queue listener class:

```
@Component
public class QueueListenerReceiveService {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
private static final Logger logger = 
Logger.getLogger(QueueListenerReceiveService.class.getName());

@JmsListener(destination = "${sqs.queue.name}", containerFactory="myFactory")   
public void receiveMessage(@Headers Map<String, Object> messageAttributes, @Payload String json) {

    try {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SQSMessage sqsMessage = objectMapper.readValue(json, SQSMessage.class);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Message Received=" + sqsMessage);
        FadeStarterService.start(sqsMessage.getUseCase(), sqsMessage.getZoneId());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   
}
```

I'm using Maven to manage dependencies, so here are the dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.311</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And finally the build tag in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>queue-listener-fade</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>locahost</hostname>
                <port>9990</port>
                <username>deplyusr</username>
                <password>pssdploy</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>      
</build>
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing?